# onclick div trigger open overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, overlay

I'm using a overlay tutorial by codrops can be found [here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/02/06/fullscreen-overlay-effects/). the person who made the tutorial used " trigger-overlay " ID on a button to trigger the overlay.

I'm trying to make the overlay trigger with a div with same id ( the id selector is used only once ) as mentioned there are no multiple instances of the id used.

I have given the div on hover cursor:pointer, i want the overlay to open when the div is clicked.

The html -

```
<div id="trigger-overlay">
     <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
 <div class="overlay overlay-hugeinc">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="large-12 small-12 medium-12 columns">
                    <button type="button" class="overlay-close right">Close</button>
                </div>
                <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns">
                    <div class="large-2 medium-2 small-12 columns">
                        <p class="main-p">About<br>Differenxia</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns">
                    <p>
                        Content for the fullscreen overlay
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Here is the script which is handling the trigger -

```
(function() {
    var triggerBttn = document.getElementById( 'trigger-overlay' ),
        overlay = document.querySelector( 'div.overlay' ),
        closeBttn = overlay.querySelector( 'button.overlay-close' );
        transEndEventNames = {
            'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
            'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
            'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
            'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
            'transition': 'transitionend'
        },
        transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ],
        support = { transitions : Modernizr.csstransitions };

    function toggleOverlay() {
        if( classie.has( overlay, 'open' ) ) {
            classie.remove( overlay, 'open' );
            classie.add( overlay, 'close' );
            var onEndTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
                if( support.transitions ) {
                    if( ev.propertyName !== 'visibility' ) return;
                    this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
                }
                classie.remove( overlay, 'close' );
            };
            if( support.transitions ) {
                overlay.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
            }
            else {
                onEndTransitionFn();
            }
        }
        else if( !classie.has( overlay, 'close' ) ) {
            classie.add( overlay, 'open' );
        }
    }

    triggerBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
    closeBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
})();
```

Classie -

```
( function( window ) {

'use strict';

// class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

function classReg( className ) {
  return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
}

// classList support for class management
// altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return elem.classList.contains( c );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.add( c );
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.remove( c );
  };
}
else {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
      elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
    }
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
  };
}

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
  var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
  fn( elem, c );
}

var classie = {
  // full names
  hasClass: hasClass,
  addClass: addClass,
  removeClass: removeClass,
  toggleClass: toggleClass,
  // short names
  has: hasClass,
  add: addClass,
  remove: removeClass,
  toggle: toggleClass
};

// transport
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
  // AMD
  define( classie );
} else {
  // browser global
  window.classie = classie;
}

})( window );
```

Comment: Can you show us the HTML?

Comment: `I'm trying to make the overlay trigger with a div with same id` - ids should be unique

Comment: I have added the html now and the id is not used in multiple places.

Comment: what is `classie`? can you provide a demo of it failing?

Comment: Added classie script also.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the HTML OR make sure that you do not have the ID used anywhere else within the HTML document.

Otherwise only the first instance of the ID will trigger the event.

IE:

```
<p><button id="trigger-overlay" type="button">Open Overlay</button></p>
<div id="trigger-overlay"><p>Testing</p></div>
```

The above top button will work, while the below Testing div will not.

If you DO want multiple areas to trigger the overlay, I would recommend importing JQuery and adding classes to the elements you want to trigger. That way you could implement the overlay toggles like so:

```
$('.triggerClass').click(function(){
    toggleOverlay();
});
```

Comment: I have added the html part.

Comment: `$('.triggerClass').click(toggleOverlay);` no need for anon functions here. FYI.

Comment: If your answer has to ask for more details, you might want to get the details before answering.